# Responsive tabs with import as module throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, webpack

I use webpack and ES6 JS modules.

I would like to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/responsive-tabs.

If I install the library as an npm package and then import it in my script: `import 'responsive-tabs';` i get an error:

```
jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(...).responsiveTabs is not a function
```

I use the library simply as follows according to the documentation:

```
    $('#tabs').responsiveTabs({
        startCollapsed: false,
    });
```

Do I have to set anything else? Or I can't use the library like this.

Comment: In your script, did you also import jQuery, *before* importing `responsive-tabs`?

Comment: Yes - import $ from 'jquery';

Comment: Try adding the jQuery script globally in its own script tag instead of importing jQuery, obviously before loading your script.

Comment: The problem is not in the jquery but in "responsiveTabs". if i try to get the element using jquery: $('.container') so i get element